# Query regarding post increment and pre increment operator

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, post-increment, pre-increment

If I have the following code:

```cpp
int n=5;
if (n++>=6){
    cout<<"Yay";
    }
else cout<<"No";
```

And I compare it with this:

```cpp
int n=5;
if (++n>=6){
    cout<<"Yay";
    }
else cout<<"No";
```

Why is the output different in both cases? Isn't n being incremented in both cases(either post/pre-increment) before the inequality is encountered?

When does the post-increment take effect-- is it just before the next statement is encountered? If this is the case, will n++ value remain 5 until the whole inequality is evaluated?

Another question I have is that will increment in the if condition affect the value of the variable outside? If I have the first code(post-increment) and I print n, will n return 6?

Comment: Note that it's the _result_ of `n++`/`++n` that participates in the comparison, not `n`. When the modification takes effect is not really relevant.

Comment: both are different things. ++n means it increments first and use in the statement while in n++ it uses same n value in statement and then increments n by 1

Comment: @cpplearner Isn't the result of both n++ and ++n supposed to be same?

Comment: Basically, @user_9, they'll both have the same "effect on `n`" result (increment `n`); the difference is in the "view `n`" result.  The easiest way to describe the semantics is that `++n` is "increment before checking", and `n++` is "check before incrementing".  (Mechanically, this means that prefix is simpler, since postfix needs to store and return `n`'s original value.)

Answer (score 0):

both are different things. ++n means it increments n by 1 first and use update value in the statement while in n++ it uses same n value in statement and then increments n by 1